# Jasmine: How to test if the correct URL has been called in a GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service whose function I'd like to test. However, I have no idea on how to mock a service function that is used inside each function in that service. I want to check, if the correct URL is called.

Here is my service:

```
angular.module("myModule").service('myService', MyService);

MyService.$inject = ['$http'];

function MyService($http) {
    var myService = this;

myService.request = function (reqType, url, headers, requestBody, fnc, fncFail) {
        $http(createRequest(reqType, point, headers, requestBody)).then(function (response) {
            if (typeof fnc == 'function') {
                fnc(response.data);
            }
        }, function (response) {
            if (typeof fncFail == 'function') {
                fncFail(response);                
            }
        });
    };

myService.getInfo = function (id, fnc, fncFail) {            
        myService.request("GET", "myURL", {"Accept":"application/json"}, null, function (data) {
          fnc(data);
        }, fncFail);
};
```

Now a snippet of my test suite:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    service = $injector.get("myService");
    httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    http = $injector.get("$http");      
}));

it("function getInfo is called with the correct URL", function () {
    spyOn(http, 'get').and.callThrough();
    myService.getInfo(id, fnc, fncFail);
    expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("myurl");
    httpBackend.flush();
});
```

I am not sure, if this is the correct approach to testing my method "getInfo" because it calls the other service function ("request").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$httpBackend` to expect XHR calls. With the following `afterEach` block the test will fail if the call is not made.

```
afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});    

it("function getInfo is called with the correct URL", function () {
    httpBackend.expect('GET', "myurl").respond(200, {mocked: "response"});
    myService.getInfo(id, fnc, fncFail);
    httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Comment: Hi again, I still have a problem because when testing a method that is actually like the one in my example, I get a `TypeError: 'null' is not a constructor` for `fnc(data);` in my function `myService.getInfo = function (id, fnc, fncFail) {            
        myService.request("GET", "myURL", {"Accept":"application/json"}, null, function (data) {
          fnc(data);
        }, fncFail);
};` Any ideas?

Comment: is `fnc` defined in your test?

Comment: Yeah but i initialized it with null: `var fnc = null;`. I also tried `fnc = new constructor();` and `fnc = new constructor("test");` but then I get the error that it's an illegal constructor (sorry, I am a newbie)...

Comment: try `var fnc = function(){}`

Comment: It works! I bow before thou Sir Bornstrand. Can you explain it to me tho :)

Comment: `fnc` needs to be a reference to a function, as the callback from ` myService.request` tries to invoke it. `var fnc = function(){}` sets fnc to an empty anonymous function that the callback can invoke. I'm not familiar with `new constructor();` so I can't say how it differs from the solution I offered.